# Domain of discourse vs First-order theory

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, smt-solvers, predicate-logic

In the question ([Validity of predicate logic formulas](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/validity-of-predicate-logic-formulas?rq=1)) I see the following way of expressing:

"The predicate $P(x,y) \equiv  \bigl[ y \cdot x = 1 \bigr]$, where the domain of discourse is $\mathbb{Q}$."

However, I am used to call this *domain of discourse* a *first-order theory*. For instance, I would have rewritten the above phrase as:

"The predicate $P(x,y) \equiv  \bigl[ y \cdot x = 1 \bigr]$, where the first-order theory is $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{Q}}$.", where $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ denotes the theory of Linear Rational/Real Arithmetic (I call them like that, since, in the linear fragment, arithmetics for $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are equivalent).

Then, my question is: which is the difference between *domain of discurse* and *first-order theory*? Someone could say that if I am using a theory, then I am accepting all of its axioms, but the same happens with domain of discourse! That is, if I say the domain of discourse is $\mathbb{Q}$, then I am accepting all the axioms of the rationals, in the same way.

Does the difference come from the signature? Maybe the domain of discourse is not specifying whether the arithmetic is linear or no?

Comment: A first-order theory is a set of axioms, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#First-order_theories,_models,_and_elementary_classes). To understand where a formula belongs you don't need to specify a first-order theory.

Comment: I suggest picking up a good textbook on first-order logic. It should contain all relevant definitions (except "domain of discourse", which I'm not sure is a standard formal notion in *mathematical* logic).

Comment: I have the problem precisely with the notion of domain of discourse.

Comment: Why after specifying a domain, you have to accept *all* of its axioms? Say if you specify your domain as $\mathbb{N}$, you don't need to accept all its usual axioms as in first order theory PA. You may only accept order relation (<) in your language and then still can prove it embeds into the $\mathbb{Q}$ line...

Comment: Hi, the answer below of @Pseudonym is not saying the contrary? I mean, that accepting naturals as discourse yields accepting all of its axioms.

Comment: @TheoDeep In general domain is only a semantic part of any first order theory, in some slightly different logic such as free logic and inclusive logic, [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Empty_domains) can even be empty with a non-emtpy theory...

Comment: So domain is like the 'type' to which the variables belong? And that domain can be empty. Need more insight on this emptynees idea.

Comment: Say as a mystic you'd like invent a mythical logic where *all* objects are non-referent fictional names from certain culture and a theory based on it saying "Pegasus is a horse" should be true under this logic. While domain is usually defined as consisting of ontologically committed entities where your variables range over per philosopher Quine's spirit, then the domain of this mythical logic needs to be totally empty, otherwise it may describe something related to the real world and atoms like isHorse(Pegasus) will be all false since truth only applies to real object if you have a domain.

Comment: Another common case is when you're dealing with first order math theories with possible empty structure, say group theory, then a model with an empty domain can still (vacuously) satisfy group theory with all its usual axioms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you're simply asking a different question than the previous questioner did.

The previous question is asking an abstract question about predicate logic, so all axioms are available. But the question could also have been expressed as a question about a specific theory, too. Asking "is $P$ a tautology where the domain of discourse is $\mathbb{N}$" is not the same question as "is $P$ a tautology in the theory of Peano arithmetic". In the former question, all axioms and theorems are available, and in the latter, you are restricting yourself to the first-order theory with addition and multiplication, plus induction.

The statement that $P\ne NP$ can be expressed as a formula in the domain of discourse $\mathbb{N}$, but not in any first-order theory.

Comment: I think you understood my question, I am precisely wondering why asking "is  a tautology where the domain of discourse is ℕ" is not the same question as "is  a tautology in the theory of Peano arithmetic". You say that in the former question, all axioms and theorems are available. Which are 'all the axioms' of predicate logic? That is the point I am missing.

Comment: You gave a good example when you noted that the linear fragment of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the same as the linear fragment of $\mathbb{R}$, but of course the first-order field theories are different; polynomials have more real solutions than rational ones. (In fact, the theory of first-order real closed fields is decidable, as shown by Tarski, but this is not true of the rationals.)

Comment: But if you're asking what there is to know about $\mathbb{N}$ apart from the Peano axioms, well, there's second-order induction as one example. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2984410/difference-between-first-and-second-order-induction

Comment: When you say the first-order field theories are different, are you referring to the nonlinear fragment? As far as I know, the nonlinear fragment of rational arithmetic is undecidable, is not it?

Comment: @TheoDeep That's correct. The first-order theory of rationals with the field operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division) is undecidable, but reals are decidable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I make a last question? I see the real closure of rationals is the set of real algebraic numbers. And I see the algebraic closure of reals is the set of complex. Is there any other witness of algebraically closed field apart from complex numbers?

Comment: Good question, and perhaps it would be better asked on [math.SE]. Obviously, the algebraic complex numbers form a (countable!) subfield of $\mathbb{C}$; I believe this is known to be decidable. I also seem to remember that there is an algebraic closure of $GF(p)$ for every prime $p$, but I can't remember how it's constructed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will make use of Mathematics' Stack.